# Чтение чисел из текстового файла в динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы, память

При попытке считывания цифр из файла и их записи в одномерный массив, считывание прекращалось при появлении первого же пробела.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace:: std;

int main(){

int input_float_vector_size=0;

float* input_float_vector = new float[input_float_vector_size]; // динамический вектор, для записи полученных из файла чисел в массив

ifstream file;

file.open("INPUT.txt");

if(!file.is_open()){

  cout << "Cant open file" << endl;

  }else{

        while(file>>input_float_vector[input_float_vector_size]){

        cout << input_float_vector[input_float_vector_size] << endl;

        input_float_vector_size++;

        }

 }

delete [] input_float_vector;

file.close();
```

return 0;

}

Этот вопрос наверняка давно имеет ответ. Однако найденные советы не помогали.
Вскоре эмпирически выяснилось, что проблема решается способом открытия самого файла.

При открытии с помощью конструктора **ifstream file("INPUT.txt")**, а не традиционно  **file.open("INPUT.txt")** все работает прекрасно!

Объясните причину.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша, гм... вобщем, неприятности тут:

```
int input_float_vector_size=0;
float* input_float_vector = new float[input_float_vector_size]; // динамический вектор, для записи полученных из файла чисел в массив
```

Выделен массив нулевой длины. Который, как бы вы ни надеялись, что, увеличивая некую переменную, он будет расти - так поверьте, это то же самое, что написать на бумажке "дай мне 100 рублей" и получив их, рассчитывать, что если вы теперь на бумажке зачеркнете 100  и напишете 10000 - то у вас от этого в кошельке что-то прибавится.

Вы пишете неизвестно куда, имея классическое "неопределенное поведение", так что то, что вам *кажется* что программа заработала - так это не так...

Можно так:

```
vector<float> input;

...

float i;
while(file >> i) input.push_back(i);
```

Можно вообще через `copy`, но это пока для вас рановато, разберитесь с этим.

Если препод требует именно через массив - то надо или брать массив заведомо больший, или при каждом чтении смотреть - заполнен выделенный массив или нет, и если да - то выделять новый побольше и перекопировать все считанное в него.

Comment: Я пробовал не использовать динамический массив. Например, использовал float a[5]; и в цикле пытался получить данные с потока в этот массив. Проблема не решалась. Так же все считывалось до первого пробела.

Comment: До 5 числа :) - дальше вы вылетали за пределы массива. Или возьмите массив размером заведомо большим, чем количество элементов в файле, или отслеживайте и постоянно выделяйте новый, больший массив и перекопируйте все в него, или возьмите готовый динамический массив, именуемый в C++ vector<float>.   И еще - вот это ваше в условии *"считывания цифр из файла"* - сбивает с толку, потому что чтение **цифр** - это посимвольное чтение, вы читаете **числа**. Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: Да, с разницей понял. Разбираюсь с  vector<float> :-)

Comment: Спасибо, все понял, заработало!

Comment: Ну, тогда принимайте ответ, нажав "птичку" слева.